# if $_GET['error'] get value and make a variable

Tags: php, error-handling

What I am trying to do is something I would of thought would be simple enough, and it is if I do the following, but it just adds more lines of code to an already big project, I thought by me making a error.php page that stores all the types of errors a user may have would make making the error system simple, however that is not the case.

Let me explain by giving you an example.

**1) User forgets password when login**

- the URL is redirected to `login?error=wpu`
- The error.php page had the following

  `<?php $denyaccess_nosession = "Sorry you tried to access a page that requires you to be login.";
  $wpu = "You have either entered a wrong email address, password or both. Please try again! <a href='forgot' title='ISOTE Forgot Details'>Click here if you forgot your login details</a>";?>`

but I have had to put the following into the index.php to get this to work

```
if($_REQUEST['error']){
        extract($_GET);
        switch ($error) {
          case 'wpu':
              $smarty->assign('error',$wpu);
          break;

          default:
            $smarty->assign('error',$denyaccess_nosession);
          break;
        }

      }
      else{
        $smarty->assign('error',$denyaccess_nosession);
      }
```

surely there us away to just have $error and it loads the correct error from the error.php

Comment: I suggest you implement a _class_ `ErrorMessage` or similar which implements those messages as constants. That way you can simply include the class implementation (or auto include it) and access the message by `ErrorMessage::MESSAGE_WPU` or similar.

Comment: Seems to me that you are expecting error.php to be the index file of a directory made. This is not the case, but can be configured using a .htaccess file containing: `DirectoryIndex error.php` This would however result in the login page also not being the default page. It might be better altogether to link to /login/error.php?error=wpu

Answer (score 0):

You can use sessions instead of relying on `$_GET`. For example, if the user has entetered either a wrong email or a wrong password you can do something like this:

```
$access = functionThatChecksEmailAndPassword($email, $password);
if($access)
{
    //Access Granted
}
else
{
    //Redirect the user to an error page
    $_SESSION['error'] = true;
    $_SESSION['errMsg'] = "You have either entered a wrong email address, password or both. Please try again!"
    header("Location: <path to error.php>");
    exit();
}
```

Then, in error.php you can check if an error has taken place.

```
session_start();
if(!$_SESSION['error'])
{
    //Show a generalized error message
}
```

This is in case the user enters the url to the error page manually or an unexpected error. Generally something you have no control over and you're not expected to provide any details

If `$_SESSION['error']` is set and it's true, you can move on and display the error message in some way

```
else
{
   $msg = $_SESSION['errMsg'];
   unset($_SESSION['error'];
   unset($_SESSION['errMsg']);
}
```

Note that you could take it one step further and create a class that's going to store all of your error messages like this:

```
class ErrorMessages
{
    const WRONG_EMAIL_PASSWORD = 'You have either entered a wrong email address, password or both. Please try again!';
    const NO_ACCESS = 'You have no permission to view this page';
}
```

**EDIT**

You can then use that class like this:

```
$_SESSION['error'] = true;
$_SESSION['errMsg'] = ErrorMessage::WRONG_EMAIL_PASSWORD;
header("Location: <path to error.php>");
exit();
```

That's provided you've included the `ErrorMessage` class at the start of the file that deals with user login

That's entirely up to you. Don't forget that you should not show detailed errors that could be used by malicious users as exploits.

Comment: Can I ask how would I call the class const?